# How so serialize an element with node name from property value

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XmlSerializerExample
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var obj = new Rows { Row = new[] { new Row { Columns = new[] { new Column { MaxLength = 5, Name = "ColumnName1", Type = "string", Value = "rah rah rah" } } } } };

            var stream = new MemoryStream();

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Rows));
            serializer.Serialize(stream, obj);

            stream.Position = 0;

            var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var str = reader.ReadToEnd();

            Console.WriteLine(str);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }

    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false, ElementName = "DATASET")]
    public class Rows
    {
        [XmlElement("ROW")]
        public Row[] Row { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
    public class Row
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public Column[] Columns { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
    public class Column
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "maxLength")]
        public int MaxLength { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This serializes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DATASET xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ROW>
      <Columns type="string" maxLength="5">
      <Name>ColumnName1</Name>rah rah rah</Columns>
  </ROW>
</DATASET>
```

But I need it to be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DATASET xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ROW>
      <ColumnName1 type="string" maxLength="5">rah rah rah</ColumnName1>
  </ROW>
</DATASET>
```

I am actually doing this the other way around - I'm trying to deserialize xml into the classes.  But it's easier this way - when I get the hang of it I'll be deserializing.

I will be calling a third party webservice that takes SQL-like parameters and returns rows and columns.  So the column names are all variable.  I need to make quite a few different queries so I'm trying to do it this way.  If you can suggest a better solution then by all means.

Comment: Instead of deleting the previous one, and asking again, improve your other question.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31877423/deserializing-xml-containing-rows-and-columns-into-simple-classes

Comment: Yeah OK, point taken

Comment: If you're using the `XmlSerializer`, I think you'll have to settle for [implementing `IXmlSerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (see here for some help doing so: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43237/How-to-Implement-IXmlSerializable-Correctly) EDIT: You can also consider building the XML more directly (for example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387089.aspx)

Comment: Right so are you saying that because of the mapping a property value to an element name?  That would appear to make sense.

Comment: @MonkeyMan: Yes. The standard `XmlSerializer` works best on a fixed schema/structure. Ideally your XML would have a fixed structure and you just serialize/deserialize that. It's not always possible (especially when depending on 3rd parties) so you might have settle with something less than ideal.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisSinclair

Comment: So to those annoyed at my deleting of the previous question, now that it appears there is no answer, what should happen to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I don't believe what you're asking for is possible using the standard attributes with `XmlSerializer`. You will have to use custom serialization/deserialization by [implementing `IXmlSerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)(here is some help for doing so: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43237/How-to-Implement-IXmlSerializable-Correctly)

You can also consider not using the `XmlSerializer` at all and instead work with the XML in a more direct fashion (perhaps via [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387089.aspx) or [`XmlReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/cc189056%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)/[`XmlWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

Use XML Linq.  No need to serialize.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = 
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" +
            "<DATASET xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">"  +
              "<ROW>" +
                  "<Columns type=\"string\" maxLength=\"5\">" + 
                  "<Name>ColumnName1</Name>rah rah rah</Columns>" + 
              "</ROW>" +
            "</DATASET>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);

            foreach (XElement row in doc.Descendants("ROW"))
            {
                // <?xml version="1.0"?>
                //<DATASET xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                //  <ROW>
                //      <ColumnName1 type="string" maxLength="5">rah rah rah</ColumnName1>
                //  </ROW>
                //</DATASET>

                List<XAttribute> attributes = row.Element("Columns").Attributes().ToList();
                XElement eName = row.Element("Columns").Element("Name");
                string name = eName.Value;
                string value = eName.NextNode.ToString();

                XElement newElement = new XElement(name,value);
                newElement.Add(attributes);
                row.Descendants().Remove();
                row.Add(newElement);   

            }


        }
    }
}
​
```